# How do we solve $x^2 + \{x\}^2 = 33$ without computer?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions, fractional-part

This is a problem taken from a group on Facebook. I wonder how to solve this without numerical process.

$x^2 + \{x\}^2 = 33\tag{1}$

My unfinished attempt:

$$\begin{align}
x^2 + \{x\}^2 &= 33\\
x^2 + \left(x - \lfloor x \rfloor\right)^2 &= 33\\
x^2 + x^2 - 2x \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor x \rfloor^2 &= 33\\
2x\left(x - \lfloor x \rfloor\right) + \lfloor x \rfloor^2 &= 33\\
2x\{x\} + \lfloor x \rfloor^2 = 33
\end{align}$$

I'm stuck at there. Also we know that the fractional part of $x$ is bounded i.e.:

$$0\leq\{x\}<1$$

From that, I can predict where the two solutions are placed at:

$$\begin{align}
0&\leq \{x\} < 1\\
0 &\leq \{x\}^2 < 1\\
x^2 &\leq x^2 + \{x\}^2 < x^2 + 1\\
x^2 &\leq 33 < x^2 + 1 \tag{$x^2 + \{x\}^2 = 33$}\\
S &= -\sqrt{33}\leq x \leq \sqrt{33} \quad \bigcap \quad  x< -\sqrt{32} \lor x > \sqrt{32}\\
\therefore S &= -\sqrt{33}\leq x < -4\sqrt2  \quad \bigcup \quad  4\sqrt{2} < x \leq \sqrt{33}\\
S &\approx -5.74456 \leq x < -5.65685  \quad \bigcup \quad  5.65685 < x \leq 5.74456
\end{align}$$

I don't know if that's even going to help. Anyway, here are the two solutions (to the original problem) that's given by Wolfram Alpha:

$$\begin{align}
x_1 &= \frac12 \left(3\sqrt{17} - 1\right) \approx -5.815\\
x_2 &= \frac12 \left(-1 - 3\sqrt{113}\right) \approx 5.685
\end{align}$$

You see $x_1$ isn't at the interval. I'm confused.

Comment: One of the answers you quoted that Wolfram give is not what I got: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2+%2B+%28x-floor%28x%29%29%5E2+%3D+33%2C+solve+for+x

Comment: @bonsoon I forgot to add the square on frac(x). Lololol.

Comment: mystery solved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ADDED EDIT BELOW.**

First note roughly we know $5\le x \le 6$ or $-6\le x \le -5$.

So we have $\{x\}=x-5$ when $x>0$ and $\{x\}=x-(-6)=x+6$ when $x<0$, using the fact that $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$, where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.

Now you solve each case separately.

When $x>0$, solve $x^2 +(x-5)^2=33$, noting we want the positive solution to this. With quadratic formula we get $\frac{5}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{41}}{2}$

And when $x<0$ solve $x^2 + (x+6)^2=33$, noting we want the negative solution between -6 and -5 to this. We get $-3 - \sqrt{15/2}$.

This matches what Wolfram give: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2+%2B+%28x-floor%28x%29%29%5E2+%3D+33%2C+solve+for+x

(Which didn't match what you quoted above.)

---

**Edit.**

As it turns out $\{x\} = frac(x)$ is not universally agreed when $x$ is negative. According to Wikipedia: "However, in case of negative numbers, there are various conflicting ways to extend the fractional part function to them" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part.

So one might also consider the alternate definition, when $x<0$, take $\{x\} = x - \lceil x \rceil$ instead, and resolve it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By the way, I'm using frac(x) instead of x - floor(x), but I got the different output from you. Here, check this out: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2+%2B+frac%28x%29%5E2+%3D+33  .... Why does this happen?

Comment: Good catch. This shows WA takes a different definition of {x} when x is negative. Seems to me that it defines frac(x) = x - ceiling(x) when x is negative. So you will have to modify accordingly if that is how you choose to define "frac(x)".

Comment: @user516076 see the section "on negative numbers" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part 
There is not really an agreed way of how to define frac(x) for negative x.

Comment: I see.. by the way thank you! And don't mind me using your method to answer the quiz on facebook. At least you have to know. :)))

Comment: @user516076 no problem. Glad we all learned something. And it's a facebook quiz, I'll be fine. Just don't steal my answers to "what kind of Harry Potter house do I belong to". (I'm assuming that is a thing, I am unfamiliar with the IP.)

Answer (score 1):

We have $0\le \{x\}^2 < 1$, so $x^2$ is between $32$ and $33$. This tells us that $\lfloor x \rfloor$ must be either $5$ or $-6$.

For the positive solution, write $x=5+y$ with $0\le y < 1$and
$$ (5+y)^2 + y^2 = 33 $$
which you can now solve for $y$ with standard methods.

The negative solution goes very similarly -- but with a different quadratic equation to solve.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't get when you wrote $0\leq y < 1$. I have tried solving those 2 and the solutions are $y=-5.71\land0.7$ and $y=0.2\land5.73$. What do we have to do with those two irrelevant solutions (the other two are relevant but negative of them)?

Comment: @user516076: The graph of $x^2+\{x\}^2$ is made up of _pieces_ of parabolas, a different parabola in each $[n,n+1)$ interval. The $y$ you're after is the the point where _one_ of the pieces crosses the horizontal line at height $33$. When we just write down the quadratic equation we also gets a spurious solution, telling you where the _entire_ parabola that particular piece was cut from also crosses back up past that horizontal line. Since it's outside the part of the parabola that goes into $x^2+\{x\}^2$, doesn't correspond to a solution to the original equation.

Answer (score 0):

${x}^{\mathrm{2}} +\left\{{x}\right\}^{\mathrm{2}} =\mathrm{33} \\ $
$-\left\{{x}\right\}\pm\sqrt{\mathrm{33}−\left\{{x}\right\}^{\mathrm{2}} }=\left[{x}\right]\in\left\{-\mathrm{6},\mathrm{5}\right\} \\ $
$\mathrm{33}−{x}^{\mathrm{2}} \in\left\{\left({x}+\mathrm{6}\right)^{\mathrm{2}} ,\left({x}−\mathrm{5}\right)^{\mathrm{2}} \right\} \\ $
$\left(\mathrm{2}{x}^{\mathrm{2}} +\mathrm{12}{x}+\mathrm{3}\right)\left({x}^{\mathrm{2}} −\mathrm{5}{x}−\mathrm{4}\right)=\mathrm{0} \\ $
${x}\in\left\{-\mathrm{3}−\frac{\sqrt{\mathrm{30}}}{\mathrm{2}},\frac{\mathrm{5}+\sqrt{\mathrm{41}}}{\mathrm{2}}\right\} \\ $

Answer (score 0):

[image: Magdy Essafty solution Picture]
My Solution for the problem-Magdy Essafty

Comment: Please do not do this image-as-answer thing.